# Update records from one table to another in different databases where condition is accomplish

Tags: mysql, performance, query-performance

I have two tables stored in two differents DBs and I need to perform some sync between both tables based on `lastmodifieddate` and `lastSyncAt`. Let's call them as `db1` and `db2`. This is the DDL schema for table `db1.reps` - the one who needs update through sync:

```
CREATE TABLE `db1.reps` (
  `veeva_rep_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `territories_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `avatar_url` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'default_avatar.png',
  `rep_type` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'VEEVA',
  `username` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `first` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `last` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `bio` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `phone` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `inactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lastLoginAt` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastSyncAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `repTokenId` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`veeva_rep_id`),
  KEY `IDX_485DE7B033B9A304` (`territories_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_485DE7B033B9A304` FOREIGN KEY (`territories_id`) REFERENCES `territories` (`veeva_territory_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

And this is the DDL for `db2.user` - kind of master:

```
CREATE TABLE `user` (
  `id` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(80) DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(40) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastmodifieddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I could do this by using programming but I want to know and learn, if this is possible, to do it through SQL. I need, foreach row, on `db2.user` perform an UPDATE on `db1.reps` but just when `db2.user.lastmodifieddate > db1.reps.lastSyncAt`, how? I must clear that `db1.reps.lastSyncAt` should be updated to `NOW()` if a UPDATE was runned on it. This is what I did so far:

```
    INSERT INTO db1.reps (
        display_name,
        username,
        `first`,
        `last`,
        email,
        lastSyncAt
    )(
        SELECT
            CONCAT(
                LCAPITAL (firstname),
                ' ',
                LCAPITAL (lastname)
            ) AS display_name,
            username,
            LCAPITAL (firstname),
            LCAPITAL (lastname),
            email,
            NOW()
        WHERE
            db1.reps.veeva_rep_id = db2.`user`.id
    )
    WHERE
        db2.`user`.lastmodifieddate > db1.reps.lastSyncAt ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE db1.reps.display_name =
    VALUES
        (
            CONCAT(
                LCAPITAL (db2.`user`.firstname),
                ' ',
                LCAPITAL (db2.`user`.lastname)
            )
        ),
        db1.reps.username =
    VALUES
        (db2.`user`.username),
        db1.reps.`first` =
    VALUES
        (LCAPITAL(db2.`user`.firstname)),
    db1.reps.`last` =
    VALUES
        (LCAPITAL(db2.`user`.lastname)),
    db1.reps.email =
    VALUES
        (db2.`user`.email)
    db1.reps.lastSyncAt =
    VALUES
        (NOW())
```

Can any give me some help?

**EDIT**

Because `db2.user` has duplicates (a table with no restrictions at all - see image below) I need to clean up a bit the trigger before execute.

[image]

This is how I am doing at SQL side:

```
SELECT
    count(*) AS reps,
    userid,
    lastmodifieddate,
    territoryid
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            userid,
            territoryid,
            count(*) AS territories
        FROM
            userterritory
        GROUP BY
            userid
        HAVING
            territories = 1
    ) T1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        id AS userid,
        lastmodifieddate
    FROM
        `user`
    WHERE
        `user`.`id` IN (
            SELECT
                userterritory.`userid`
            FROM
                userterritory
        )
) T2 USING (userid)
GROUP BY
    territoryid
HAVING
    reps = 1
```

The query above guarantee to me just on reps to one territory as should be. How I should modify the trigger to accomplish this?

NOTE: `LCAPITAL()` is a function I have for normalize strings

Comment: Make a `TRIGGER` on `db2.user` that updates every row in `db1.reps` when `db2.user.lastmodifieddate > db1.reps.lastSyncAt`?

Comment: @oNare ummm how?

Comment: I'll make the `TRIGGER` as soon as sit in one machine.

Comment: @oNare Many thx, I wish I could understand the `TRIGGER` well because I need to replicate almost the same with other tables this is just an start point ;)

Comment: So, you want to `UPDATE db1.reps.lastSyncAt` when the column `db2.user.lastmodifieddate` is modificated and the `db2.user.lastmodifieddate` > `db1.reps.lastSyncAt`?

Comment: No, take `db2.user` as master and `db1.reps` as slave or kind of so `db2.user` is kind of equivalent to `db1.reps` so, I should, if record (from db1) doesn't exists at db2 then I insert it, otherwise I should update its columns, clear?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25484/discussion-between-reynierpm-and-onare).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `TRIGGER` to update `db1.reps.lastSyncAt` when `db2.user.lastmodifieddate` is updated.

Trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS db2.user_BEFORE_UPDATE$$
USE `db2`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `db2`.`user_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN


    SET @UserVerification=(select reps.veeva_rep_id from db1.reps where reps.veeva_rep_id=OLD.id);
    IF (@UserVerification>0) then
        SET @UserLastMod=(SELECT reps.lastSyncAt FROM db1.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=OLD.id LIMIT 0,1); 
        IF (NEW.lastmodifieddate > @UserLastMod) THEN
            # [Will update lastSyncAT to NEW.lastSyncAt]
            UPDATE db1.reps 
            SET reps.lastSyncAt = NEW.lastmodifieddate,
            reps.updatedAt=now() WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=OLD.id; 
        END IF;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO db1.reps
        (veeva_rep_id,territories_id,display_name,avatar_url,rep_type,username,first,last,title,bio,phone,email,inactive,lastLoginAt,lastSyncAt,repTokenId,createdAt,updatedAt)
        select
            u.id,
            null as territories_id,
            test.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(u.lastname,' ',u.firstname)) as display_name,
            'default avatar url' as avatar_url,
            'VEEVA' as rep_type,
            u.username,
            u.firstname as first,
            u.lastname as last,
            null as title,
            null as bio,
            null as phone,
            u.email,
            '' as inactive,
            null as lastLoginAt,
            u.lastmodifieddate as lastSyncAt,
            null as repTokenId,
            now() as createdAt,
            now() as updatedAt
        from db2.user as u
        where u.id = OLD.id;
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

And if you want to `INSERT` into `reps` table when any row is add in `user` table:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS db2.user_ai$$
USE `db2`$$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `db2`.`user_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO pdone.reps
(veeva_rep_id,territories_id,display_name,avatar_url,rep_type,username,first,last,title,bio,phone,email,inactive,lastLoginAt,lastSyncAt,repTokenId,createdAt,updatedAt)
select
    NEW.id,
    null as territories_id,
    test.LCAPITAL(CONCAT(NEW.lastname,' ',NEW.firstname)) as display_name,
    'default avatar url' as avatar_url,
    'VEEVA' as rep_type,
    NEW.username,
    NEW.firstname as first,
    NEW.lastname as last,
    null as title,
    null as bio,
    null as phone,
    NEW.email,
    '' as inactive,
    null as lastLoginAt,
    NEW.lastmodifieddate as lastSyncAt,
    null as repTokenId,
    now() as createdAt,
    now() as updatedAt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

By the way, you have to change your tables datatypes because 75-80% are just `VARCHARs`. The function `LCAPITAL` that I made can be use with more than 1 word, example:

`SELECT test.LCAPITAL(CONCAT('oanRE',' ','AnTIGUA'));`

Result:

```
Oanre Antigua
```