# Trigger is failing with no errors at all, why?

Tags: trigger, mariadb

I need to UPDATE `territory_id` column at `pdone.reps` table by using and filtering results from `veeva_new.userterritory` so based on the answer I got [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/105872/8227) I am trying to build my own and this is how it looks like:

```
USE `veeva_new`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veeva_new.userterritory_ai$$
USE `veeva_new`$$
    CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`userterritory_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `userterritory` FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
    SET @TerritoryVerification=(select reps.veeva_rep_id from pdone.reps where reps.veeva_rep_id=NEW.userid);

    IF (@TerritoryVerification>0) THEN
        SET @TerritoryLastMod=(SELECT reps.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=NEW.userid LIMIT 0,1); 

        IF (NEW.lastmodifieddate > @TerritoryLastMod) THEN
            UPDATE pdone.reps 
            SET reps.territories_id = NEW.territoryid, reps.lastSyncAt = NEW.lastmodifieddate, reps.updatedAt=now() 
            WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=NEW.userid; 
        END IF;
    END IF;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But it's not working since insertion on `veeva_new` DB just stop with no errors, I just see this in `general.log`:

```
 11 Query COMMIT
           11 Query SELECT sync_time FROM _sync_history WHERE object_name='userterritory' ORDER BY sync_time DESC LIMIT 1
150703 12:48:42    11 Query START TRANSACTION
           11 Query INSERT INTO _sync_history (object_name, sync_time) VALUES('userterritory', '2015-07-03 17:18:26')
           11 Query INSERT INTO userterritory (id,lastmodifieddate,userid,territoryid) VALUES('04S80000000uZi9EAE','2009-08-24 17:56:49','00580000001sYARAA2','04T800000008yHOEAY'),('04S80000000uoFIEAY','2009-09-24 19:20:02','00580000002Ka2yAAC','04T800000008yHOEAY')$
           11 Query SET @UserVerification=(select reps.veeva_rep_id from pdone.reps where reps.veeva_rep_id=NEW.userid)
           11 Query ROLLBACK
           11 Quit
```

This is the schema for `veeva_new.userterritory` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `userterritory` (
  `id` varchar(18) NOT NULL,
  `userid` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `territoryid` varchar(18) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastmodifieddate` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

`reps.territories_id` has a constraint against `reps.territories` and this is the schema for `reps.territories` table:

```
CREATE TABLE `territories` (
  `veeva_territory_id` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `district` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `inactive` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `createdAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updatedAt` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`veeva_territory_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

What is wrong on my trigger?

Comment: Can you post your `userterritory_ai` `CREATE TABLE` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
USE `veeva_new`;

DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS veeva_new.userterritory_ai$$
USE `veeva_new`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `veeva_new`.`userterritory_ai` AFTER INSERT ON `userterritory` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    # [ VARIABLES DECLARATION ]
    DECLARE vUserID VARCHAR(18) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerritoriRep VARCHAR(45) DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE vTerrytoriLastMod DATETIME DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00';
    # [ VARIABLES ASIGNATION ]
    SET vUserID         =NEW.userid;
    SET vTerritoriRep   =(select IFNULL(reps.territories_id,'N/A') from pdone.reps where reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);
    SET vTerrytoriLastMod=(SELECT reps.lastSyncAt FROM pdone.reps WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID LIMIT 0,1);

IF (NEW.territoryid != vTerritoriRep) THEN
    UPDATE pdone.reps 
    SET reps.territories_id = NEW.territoryid, 
        reps.lastSyncAt = IF(NOW()>vTerrytoriLastMod,NOW(),reps.lastSyncAt), 
        reps.updatedAt=now() 
    WHERE reps.veeva_rep_id=vUserID; 
END IF;

END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Assuming `veeva_rep_id` = `NEW.userid` (from `userterritory`).

This will update `reps.territories_id` when the `NEW.territoryid` is updated, `reps.lastSyncAt` when `reps.lastSyncAt` be greater than `@TerritoryLastMod` and `reps.updatedAt = now()`, current timestamp.

Comment: I got this error `Error Code: 1363. There is no OLD row in on INSERT trigger`

Comment: I updated the answer. I though it was a `AFTER UPDATE`.

Comment: Didn't work, the same issue as before still

Comment: Does your `reps.territories_id` have a `FK`?

Comment: Yes, it have a constraint against `territories` table

Comment: Thx, a bad `COLLATE` in tables was causing a bad behavior among tables, now it works